# How to obtain objectId from a parse user?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

When I print user, I get : {"objectId":"insertSomeValue"} as output. But I cannot obtain the value of that objectId and store it in a string variable. How do I obtain it?

I tried user.get("objectId") and user["objectId"] but they just return "No message provided" when fed to console.log. Do I have to fetch user before I can get its objectId?

```
var query = new Parse.Query("HelperRating");
var newProfiles = {};
var eachPromise = Parse.Promise.as();
eachPromise = eachPromise.then(function() {
    return query.each(
        function (helperRating) {
            var user = helperRating.get("helper");
            var userId = user.objectId; // How do I get this?

            console.log(user);
            console.log(user.get("objectId")); // I tried these but it prints "No message provided" instead
            //console.log(user["objectId"]);
            var newRating = helperRating.get("rating");

            // Calculate without querying
            if (newProfiles.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
                newProfiles[userId][0] = 10;
            } else {
                newProfiles[userId] = [];
                newProfiles[userId].push(1);
            }

            return;
        }
    );

    return eachPromise;
}).then(function(){
    var promises = [];
    for (var userId in newProfiles) {
        if (newProfiles.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
            var query = new Parse.Query("UserProfile");
            query.equalTo("owner", userId);
            var promise = query.find().then(
                function (results) {
                    // Do something
                }
            );
            promises.push(promise);
        }
    }

    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
});
```

Comment: Do you think you could edit your question to show a minimal example that demonstrates the problem rather than so much of your app specific code.

Comment: You have to access the property with the parse sdk model getter method: `newProfiles.get(userId)`

Comment: You are setting `newProfiles[userId] = [];` above so you should expect each item of newProfiles to be an array.

Comment: `var userId = user.id;`

Comment: @danh would you like to make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objectId in the JS SDK is given by `var userId = user.id`